# Neo4j - Architecture, Java API & Persistence

Tags: java, neo4j

I just loved the concept of Graph Based Databases, specifically Neo4j. I have some queries:

1. Is there any Architecture document on Neo4j? I specifically want to know, suppose if I use Java API how the graph would persist in memory? I mean to say I want to create the graph once and then search multiple times however when we work on NEo4j Java API when the program terminates everything is lost, so how to persist it in memory. Where are the data files stored on disk?
2. Is there any way to create database from the Java API but use the http://localhost:7474/db/ interface to see the nodes graphically?

Thanks. Eagerly waiting for replies as I have gone crazy over Neo4j to solve one of my problem.

Thanks,
Yavar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Data is persisted to disk when the transaction is *marked as successful and finished*. You can read more about transactions here:

   - [manual](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/transactions.html)
   - [apidocs](http://api.neo4j.org/current/org/neo4j/graphdb/Transaction.html)
   - [code examples](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/tutorials-java-embedded.html)
2. Yes, have a look at [Using the server with an embedded database](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/server-embedded.html)!